# SQL ORDER BY clause Advance

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select Preferred_supplier,VENDOR_NAME,VENDOR_SITE_CODE 
from ( select SUPPLIER_ID,SUPPLIER_SITE_ID,  
              VENDOR_NAME, VENDOR_SITE_CODE ,Approved_supplier,Preferred_supplier
         from xx_po_vendorssites_v 
         order by (case Approved_supplier='YES' and Preferred_supplier ='YES' 
             THEN Preferred_supplier END) DESC,
                  VENDOR_NAME ASC,
                  VENDOR_SITE_CODE ASC
     );
```

The suppliers will be sorted as below:

- First, the suppliers which have a setup in the approved supplier list for the requested category and also marked as ‘Preferred’ will be shown in alphabetical order (0 → 9; a → z).
- Second, the suppliers marked as ‘Preferred’ at header level only, will be shown in alphabetical order (0 → 9; a → z).
- Then the remaining suppliers (0 → 9; a → z).

It is not working as expected. Please help.

Comment: `prefered`, `preffered`, or (actual spelling) `preferred`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but the outer query seems not necessary to me. My approach would be:

```
select Preferred_supplier, VENDOR_NAME, VENDOR_SITE_CODE
from xx_po_vendorssites_v 
order by case 
    WHEN Approved_supplier='YES' and Preferred_supplier ='YES' THEN 1
    WHEN Approved_supplier='NO' and Preferred_supplier ='YES' THEN 2 
    ELSE 3
END ASC, VENDOR_NAME ASC, VENDOR_SITE_CODE ASC
```

Comment: @ArunGoWdA  . . . If this works, you should consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a note, I think you can simplify the logic to:

```
order by Preferred_supplier desc, Approved_supplier desc,
         vendor_name, vendor_site_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this works?

```
select Preferred_supplier,VENDOR_NAME,VENDOR_SITE_CODE 
  from ( select SUPPLIER_ID,SUPPLIER_SITE_ID,  
                VENDOR_NAME, VENDOR_SITE_CODE ,Approved_supplier,Preferred_supplier
     from xx_po_vendorssites_v 
     order by DECODE(preferred_supplier||Approved_supplier, 'YESYES', 1, 0) DESC,
              DECODE(preferred_supplier, 'YES', 1, 0) DESC, supplier,
              VENDOR_NAME ASC,
              VENDOR_SITE_CODE ASC
 );
```

Comment: Sorry it is not working. Please help. 2nd record must appear first

Prefeered_supp   Vendor_name          vendor_site_code     approved_supp
YES                      15-1 DIFFUSION      LYON  3 EME                  NO
YES                      AGENCIA                 MADRID                          YES
YES                      Test Supplier        Test Address1                  NO
NO  HORIBA JOBIN YVON S.A.S.      LONGJUMEAU          NO
NO 010COM                                        MONTEILS                        NO
NO 1 & 1 INTERNET                        SARREGUEMINES          NO